# Magento 2 What is Alternative of Zend\Form\Annotation\Object in php 7.2

Tags: magento2, php-7, object

i was using PHP 7.0 i used to use Zend\Form\Annotation\Object Now i have upgraded my system to 7.2 and Now i am getting an error that

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot use Zend\Form\Annotation\Object as Object
>   because 'Object' is a special class name

please suggest me Alternative for this class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE #1**

If you look at the source file you can see they have added a note

> Since PHP 7 adds "object" as a reserved keyword, we can no longer have
>   a class  * named that and retain PHP 7 compatibility. The original
>   class has been  * renamed to "Instance", and this class is now an
>   extension of it. It raises an  * E_USER_DEPRECATED to warn users to
>   migrate.

So as advised, use **Zend\Form\Annotation\Instance** instead of **Zend\Form\Annotation\Object**

> from PHP 7.2+ onwards the **ClassName will not be allowed to be named after
>   special / reserverd keywords like Object**.

So either you need to upgrade your Magento version which is compatible with PHP 7.2+ (Yah sounds terrible) or downgrade your PHP version.

Good news, you are not alone, there are people out there facing this issue and this one can fix your issue. (Hope it will)

https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchBundle/issues/828#issuecomment-443437917

Comment: so whats alernative of `Zend\Form\Annotation\Object` class in 7.2 any idea?

Comment: @WaqarAli yes use Zend\Form\Annotation\Instance instead of Object, checked the updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much dude you are my Hero

Comment: happy that it helps you dude, God Bless Pakistan !